# Difference between UIView frame.size.width vs frame.width

Tags: uiview, frame

```
var view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width:50, height: 30))
println(view.frame.size.width)
println(view.frame.width)
```

They both print out the same value, whats the difference between these two? Are there some specific scenarios where a particular one should be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CGRect extension has width and height properties as **get** method.

```
struct CGRect {
    var origin: CGPoint
    var size: CGSize
}

extension CGRect {
    var width: CGFloat { get }
    var height: CGFloat { get }
}
```

Basically they are the same the difference is

- `frame.width = 5` is not possible
- `frame.size.width = 5` is possible